# Not unique table/alias SQL

Tags: mysql

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT people.occupation_code,people.country_of_birth,"
                + " countries.currency_name, countries.telephone_code "
                + "FROM people,countries"
                + "WHERE people.country_of_birth = countries.name ");
```

I am currently working with MySQL databases and when I compiled the program I had : Not unique table/alias: 'people'.
Looked at previous problems connected with this and found that usually it appears when you join two tables. But I didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FROM people,countries"
+ "WHERE people.country_of_birth = countries.name ");
```

You need a space after countries.

```
FROM people,countries "
+ "WHERE people.country_of_birth = countries.name ");
```